# PHP Imagick API: How to change the Hue of an Image to known hexadecimal value

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I create template websites. If a client choose a blue or green or purple heading, I don't want to have to store all those different color variations of an image. I want to programmatically change the hue. I do not want to 'flood fill' it because that would remove any textures or bevels.

For example page you see I have accomplished exactly what I want.
http://sta.oursitesbetter.com/test/index.php

I have done this using Imagick modulateImage function.

HOWEVER, I am just throwing random 'Hue' values and not RGB values.  I want to accomplish this same thing feeding RGB values.  I need a function similar to modulateImage however it must take RGB as value and set the image to that hue.

I have studied for the past 5 hours and cannot figure out how to do it.  I need help.

Has any of the gurus of StackOverflow got a PHP Imagick solution to this color quandary?

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia: Hue #Computing hue from RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue#Computing_hue_from_RGB):

[image: \tan h_{Preucil\ hexagon} = \frac{\sqrt{3}\cdot (G - B)}{2\cdot R - G - B}]

```
$hex=(sqrt(3)*($green-$blue)) /
       (2*($red-$green-$blue));//$red, $green and $blue are each a value in the range 0->255


$img->modulateImage(100, 100, intval($hex*100/256));
//probably 256->100 value above will work, if didn't , try with the following insead.
//$img->modulateImage(100, 100, $hex);
```

Comment: Thank you. Conceptually it seemed to have promise but in practice it returned complete a black image in both cases.

Comment: @Jay No, but now I'm interested to try it, I'll do a check after a while with some debugging to see if it works or need some modifications. (Your `$red`, `$green`, `$blue` are all `0->255` right? )

Comment: @Jay Edited, I have swapped parameters accidentally, now fixed.

Comment: Yes, my red, green, blue ->255
Did you upload the code changes that are working?

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to use ImageMagick to create a single pixel image in the RGB colour you want and then see what ImageMagick makes that in HSL colorspace. Say your RGB values are 25,126,200, you could do this:

```
convert -size 1x1! xc:rgb\(25,126,200\) -colorspace HSL txt:-
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,65535,hsl
0,0: (57.0474%,77.7783%,44.1184%)  #920AC71C70F1  hsl(57.0474%,77.7783%,44.1184%)
```

The following equivalent methods are maybe a little more succinct:

```
convert xc:rgb\(25,126,200\) -format "%[fx:100*p{0,0}.hue]" info:
57.0476

convert xc:rgb\(25,126,200\) -format "%[fx:100*hue]" info:
57.0476
```

So, IM makes that a Hue of 57.0474%. Of course you don't need to run that and parse the text output, I am only doing that to demonstrate the concept - you can access the pixel directly in PHP.